# Need 10 intervals between two time stamps

Tags: php

I need 10 intervals between two time stamps. Please find the example below.

start_date: 2021-01-15 15:45:00
end_date: 2021-01-15 18:00:00

I need result like below based on count of intervals. I can change 5 interval or 7 intervals but the time need to calculate automatically based on intervals

1. 15:45:00
2. 16:00:00
3. 16:15:00
4. 16:30:00
5. 16:45:00
6. 17:00:00
7. 17:15:00
8. 17:30:00
9. 17:45:00
10. 18:00:00

```
function SplitTime($StartTime, $EndTime, $Duration="60"){

    $ReturnArray = array ();// Define output
    $StartTime    = strtotime ($StartTime); //Get Timestamp
    $EndTime      = strtotime ($EndTime); //Get Timestamp
    $AddMins  = $Duration * 60;
    while ($StartTime <= $EndTime) //Run loop
    {
        $ReturnArray[] = date ("G:i:s", $StartTime);
        $StartTime += $AddMins; //Endtime check
    }
    return $ReturnArray;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried, your best attempt (code). SO is not a code writing service. Please read [ask].

Comment: I can get the intervals between times, but i need time based on interval count


function SplitTime($StartTime, $EndTime, $Duration="60"){
    $ReturnArray = array ();// Define output
    $StartTime    = strtotime ($StartTime); //Get Timestamp
    $EndTime      = strtotime ($EndTime); //Get Timestamp

    $AddMins  = $Duration * 60;

    while ($StartTime <= $EndTime) //Run loop
    {
        $ReturnArray[] = date ("G:i:s", $StartTime);
        $StartTime += $AddMins; //Endtime check
    }
    return $ReturnArray;
}

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments like that. As you can see yourself, it's not very readable. Your question has an "edit" button... please use that to update your main post with the additional information. thanks.

Comment: check now please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a division of the number of seconds between the 2 dates :

```
function SplitTime($StartTime, $EndTime, $Division = 10){
    $ReturnArray = array (); // Define output
    $StartTime = strtotime ($StartTime); //Get Timestamp
    $EndTime = strtotime ($EndTime); //Get Timestamp

    //Time diff
    $diff = $EndTime - $StartTime;
    // number of seconds by "step"
    $num = $diff / ($Division - 1);
    
    for ($inum = 0; $inum < $Division; $inum++)
    {
        $ReturnArray[] = date ("G:i:s", $StartTime + $num * $inum);
    }
    return $ReturnArray;
}


$dates = SplitTime("2021-01-15 15:45:00", "2021-01-15 18:00:00");
print_r($dates);
```

Outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15:45:00
    [1] => 16:00:00
    [2] => 16:15:00
    [3] => 16:30:00
    [4] => 16:45:00
    [5] => 17:00:00
    [6] => 17:15:00
    [7] => 17:30:00
    [8] => 17:45:00
    [9] => 18:00:00
)
```

See [online demo](https://3v4l.org/BJ8kb)